# How close Window from thread on Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, mvvm

My app has a Window and I put a frame with page into a grid. Than in Page1.cs I start thread with "while". After execute while window with page must be closed.

I can't use this method `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

Because this closes all windows, so if I have in my app a few windows after this method all windows will be closed.

I thought about using MVVM but I don't know how.

I want to close one Window from thread on Page.(for example in method `update()`)

MainWindow.xaml

```html
<Windowx:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Frame Source "Page1.xaml">

    </Frame>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Page1.xaml

```html
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page1">
  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Than I start thread in Page1.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// 
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// 
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        bool isTrue = false;
        int i;
        private MainWindow vm = new MainWindow();
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread thread = null;

            thread = new Thread(() => update());
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }

        void update()
        {

            while (i<50000)
            {
                i++;

            }
            ***//How I can close window from this place***
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(Application.Current.MainWindow.Close)); // this don't work 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to close the main window, or the page1?

Comment: I'm trying to close Window. but don't work. I have error or nothing. Error about invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to `vm` (or page) to close. E.g.:

```
vm.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => vm.Close());
```

---

From other thought I think this line is your problem

```
private MainWindow vm = new MainWindow();
```

If you create here **another instance** of MainWindow, then obviously `vm` is useless and then you have to do it in very similar to yours way:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
});
```

---

I've to try to see the problem, which is access to dispatcher of main window.

This is working solution (using `UserControl`, shouldn't matter):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private Dispatcher _dispatcher; // store dispatcher when constructor is called

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher;

        var thread = new Thread(() => update());
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    void update()
    {
        // simulate some work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // close
        _dispatcher.Invoke(() => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work. Don't do anything. Window continue work after use your code,

Comment: Doesn't work. I have the same error.  **"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"**

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. Why it worked on UserControl but didn't work on Page?

Comment: It should work with `Page`, just copy all code parts containing `_dispatcher` into your code.